# " Battery full " notification for 16.04

Tags: 16.04, battery, notification

Is there any software which can alert me when battery is 100 % ? I do not want to keep charging further causing battery damage. I use 16.04 LTS.

Comment: You may want to read [this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/leave-laptop-plugged-time/), it seems that keeping the changer connected when charge reach 100% will not affect battery life.

Comment: I think a slight modification of Serg's script at http://askubuntu.com/a/603322/15003 will work here.

Comment: I don't think keeping the charger in for a while at 100% does very much. If you keep it in all the time, then it can, but otherwise there's nothing permanent.

Comment: I can write a different script that does notify the user, if you want. Let me know if the old version is OK, and if not - I can do new one. I can add sound or pop-up notification.

Answer (score 1):

You Dont Need To Be Notified.
 I have Dell laptop and I keep it plugged in all the time and I dont bother about the 100 %. Because the hardware has built-in safety against over charge. Furthermore upon wanderinig through internet, and through personal experience I've discovered that for long healthy battery life:

- Once you unplug after a full charge let it dfrain upto atleast 60% before plugging it again. That also applies for battery level more than 60%.
- let it drain to critical level atleast once in six months before plugging in.
- A healthy battery gives Average of 2-7 hrs.
- Average laptop battery life is 4 years max(that is alot).