# No low battery popup notification in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, low-power

I use Unity in 16.04. For some reason, I am not getting popup notifications for low battery. I have to rely on battery icon in top panel to see if battery is on the " low battery " side. Is the default behaviour in 16.04 ? Or I am not getting pop ups for low battery ?

Comment: You might try reinstalling`indicator-power ` package。 If you want, i could also provide a script that can give you notification

Comment: Thanks @Serg , kindly give me the commands to do the same.

Comment: ok, i will post an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: comments under my post have been moved to chat. We can continue troubleshooting there.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Is this a low laptop battery or the motherboard battery. Does the solution discussed also refer to the motherboard's cmos battery normally used for keeping the clock alive?

Comment: @simgineer This involves laptop battery, which typically has required sensors to provide necessary information. I'm not aware what method, if any, exist to check CMOS battery voltage.

Comment: same problem on 18.04, I saw a tiny red dot on top left inside battery icon and found out power was disconnected! good I wasn't too long away from it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attempt reinstalling `indicator-power` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-power
```

If that doesn't solve the issue, consider using the battery monitoring script as provided by one of my previous answers : https://askubuntu.com/a/603322/295286

Below is python script that can notify  you when battery charge gets past certain percentage, and suspend system once it is bellow 10 %.
Usage is simple:

```
python battery_monitor.py INT
```

Where INT is integer value of your desired  battery percentage at which you should receive notification, for example `30`.

You can also add the above command to Startup Applications to start this script on every login into Unity session

#### Source code

As per OP requests in chat and comments , the script now takes two arguments, first for discharge notification and second os for charge notification.

Also available as [Github Gitst](https://gist.github.com/SergKolo/16c0eb09d232461a773c22803a3df35e)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gi.repository import Notify
import subprocess
from time import sleep, time
from sys import argv
import dbus


def send_notification(title, text):
    try:
        if Notify.init(argv[0]):
            n = Notify.Notification.new("Notify")
            n.update(title, text)
            n.set_urgency(2)
            if not n.show():
                raise SyntaxError("sending notification failed!")
        else:
            raise SyntaxError("can't initialize notification!")
    except SyntaxError as error:
        print(error)
        if error == "sending notification failed!":
            Notify.uninit()
    else:
        Notify.uninit()


def run_cmd(cmdlist):
    try:
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    else:
        if stdout:
            return stdout


def run_dbus_method(bus_type, obj, path, interface, method, arg):
    if bus_type == "session":
        bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    if bus_type == "system":
        bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    proxy = bus.get_object(obj, path)
    method = proxy.get_dbus_method(method, interface)
    if arg:
        return method(arg)
    else:
        return method()


def suspend_system():
    run_dbus_method('session',
                    'com.canonical.Unity',
                    '/com/canonical/Unity/Session',
                    'com.canonical.Unity.Session',
                    'Suspend', 'None')


def get_battery_percentage():
    output = run_cmd(['upower', '--dump']).decode().split('\n')
    found_battery = False
    for line in output:
        if 'BAT' in line:
            found_battery = True
        if found_battery and 'percentage' in line:
            return line.split()[1].split('%')[0]


def main():
    end = time()
    battery_path = ""
    for line in run_cmd(['upower', '-e']).decode().split('\n'):
        if 'battery_BAT' in line:
            battery_path = line
            break
    while True:
        notified = False
        while subprocess.call(['on_ac_power']) == 0:

            sleep(0.25)
            run_dbus_method('system', 'org.freedesktop.UPower',
                            battery_path, 'org.freedesktop.UPower.Device',
                            'Refresh', 'None')
            battery_percentage = int(get_battery_percentage())
            if battery_percentage == int(argv[2]) and not notified:
               subprocess.call( ['zenity', '--info','--text', 'Battery reached' + argv[2] + '%'  ]  ) 
               notified = True
        while subprocess.call(['on_ac_power']) == 1:

            sleep(0.25)
            run_dbus_method('system', 'org.freedesktop.UPower',
                            battery_path, 'org.freedesktop.UPower.Device',
                            'Refresh', 'None')
            battery_percentage = int(get_battery_percentage())

            if battery_percentage <= int(argv[1]):
                if battery_percentage <= 10:
                    send_notification('Low Battery',
                                      'Will suspend in 60 seconds')
                    sleep(60)
                    suspend_system()
                    continue
                if end < time():
                    end = time() + 600
                    send_notification('Low Battery', 'Plug in your charger')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42862/discussion-between-serg-and-user227495).

Answer (score 10):

This is not normal i have a 16.04 running and get popups but i'm using a gnome shell tho.

You can make a script that gives you a message.

```
battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'`
if [ $battery_level -le 10 ]
then
    notify-send "Battery low" "Battery level is ${battery_level}%!"
fi
```

Then make a cron job and run it every few minutes.

Comment: Thanks @Arne N. I do not know how to run corn jobs though. Also, any way to fi the core files so that we can skip the script ?

Comment: To make a cron job open up the terminal type in `crontab -e` choose the nano editor (only if you never made a cron job) by pressing 2 and enter, after that a file wil open scroll down to the bottom and add a new line. `/2 * * * * my-script.sh`

Press `ctrl + x` and then type `y`and enter. 

That should work.

No idea about the core files  sorry.

Comment: Will do. I am still trying it one by one. Was hoping to fix it through core files.

Comment: thx! I put this command at startupapps `bash -c 'while true;do n="$(acpi -b |egrep "[[:digit:]]*%" -o |tr -d "%")";declare -p n;if((n<30));then notify-send "Low battery warning!" "$n%";fi;sleep $((5*60));done'`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, This is normal. I have written a simple bash script for setting up battery notifications.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# check if acpi is installed.
if [ `dpkg -l | grep acpi | grep -v acpi-support | grep -v acpid | grep -c acpi` -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "run 'sudo apt install acpi' then run '$0' again."
    exit
fi

if [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" == "--install" ]; then
    echo "installing battery notifier..."

    if [ ! -e "$HOME/bin" ]; then
        mkdir $HOME/bin
    fi  

    cp $0 $HOME/bin/bn.sh
    (crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/2 * * * * $HOME/bin/bn.sh") | crontab -

else
    # check if power adapter is plugged in, if not, check battery status.
    if [ -z "`acpi -a | grep on-line`" ]; then
        batlvl=`acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'`

        if [ $batlvl -le 15 ] && [ $batlvl -ge 11 ]; then
            notify-send "Battery is at $batlvl%. Please plug your computer in."
        elif [ $batlvl -le 10 ] && [ $batlvl -ge 6 ]; then
            notify-send "Battery is at $batlvl%. Computer will shutdown at 5%."
        elif [ $batlvl -le 5 ]; then
            notify-send "BATTERY CRITICALLY LOW, SHUTTING DOWN IN 3 SECONDS!"
            sleep 3
            shutdown -h now
        fi
    fi  
fi
```

I also Have this and instructions on my [github account](https://github.com/nwneal/Ubuntu-16-battery-notification). I hope this helps and makes it easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent app that does it for low battery, full battery and so on.

Read this

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/ubuntu-battery-monitor-notifications