# Bionic: Block Notification: laptop Battery Critically Low

Tags: power-management, 18.04, gui, battery, notification

Problem: My laptop battery is broken, it never charges. I have to use it at 0% battery and on AC power. Ubuntu 18.04, keeps giving me annoying notification **every 5 seconds**: [image]

**I know several questions have been asked on this topic, but this is specifically for about Ubuntu 18.04.** I have tried solutions mentioned for older versions of Ubuntu but none of them work:

- Modifying /etc/UPower/UPower.conf
- Modifying `dconf editor` ->`org` -> `gnome` -> `settings-daemon` -> `plugins` -> `power`

I am surprised that these settings don't point to the same values? I can set different values in these and still nothing happens. Do these settings even work or are they deprecated?

Has anybody else faced this issue? It's very annoying.

Comment: I use my laptop with the battery removed and get no warnings, does this work for you?

Comment: That's not recommended as all the oscillations in electric current would spoil hardware.

Comment: I've not heard that before, do you have any reference documents/articles? I've been running my Samsung laptop without a battery for over 5 years without any hardware issues.

Comment: also, why is a laptop without a battery any different from a desktop?

Comment: Try setting org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy false, then setting org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low and related settings to 0

Comment: @vanadium my gnome 3.28 dconf has none of these

Answer (score 4):

I found these commands did the trick:-

```
~$ dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/use-time-for-policy false
~$ dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/percentage-low 0
```

you can check the dconf edit worked like so:-

```
~$ dconf dump /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/
[/]
percentage-low=0
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=3600
sleep-inactive-ac-type='nothing'
use-time-for-policy=false
```

@vanadium provided the correct keys and values to update. The keys were missing from my dconf but adding them seems to have solved the problem.