# Is there an app to lower the battery charge max?

Tags: xubuntu, battery

I use a Lenovo ThinkPad T420. Is there an app to limit what level the battery charges to, or to notify me when the charge reaches 70%?

Comment: You can write a script that sends a bubble notification to desktop and issues a system alert sound when battery hits 70%. Can I ask though why you want to be told when it hits 70%? Also because of delays in polling the battery you might want the message fine-tuned to check 65-75% first and then narrow the range 66-74%, etc. if the message appears too often. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/603285/how-to-monitor-battery-condition-and-pop-up-notification

Comment: Have a look at the [`tlp`](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) tool.

Answer (score 1):

Install [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) and configure the [upper charge threshold](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#chargethresholds).

Comment: I see you frequently seem to link your own website in your answers. While this is generally okay if it supports the answer, you have to disclose your affiliation so that it will not possibly regarded spam. Please have a look at https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion. It would also be preferable if you include at least all relevant information and instructions directly into the answer, so that it stays useful even if the link dies some day.

Comment: @ByteCommander : I prefer to keep the links alive. How do I best disclose my affiliation?

Comment: There is no specific rule about the "how", I think. You just have to make clear that the linked website/article/whatever is yours. Embedding your links with phrases like "I have written a more detailed article about this [here]" or "For a more detailed explanation, have a look at my post [there]" or something similar should suffice in general. There is still the no-link-only-answer rule though, which can be approximated as "if all links were dead, the post should still be informative", so don't rely on your links only but replicate at least the key points here.