# How to show (just) the IP address of my router?

Tags: command-line, networking, ip, router

What command can I run to get just the IP address of my router?

With this command I should have only IP of my router and not, for example, the whole routing table (as when I run `route -n`).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

One-liners:

- `nm-tool | grep -i gateway | xargs echo | cut -d' ' -f2`
- `nm-tool | grep -i gateway | awk '{print $2}`
- `netstat -nr | awk '$1 == "0.0.0.0"{print$2}'`
- `arp -n | awk '{print $1}'` Note: works only if your machine is the only one on the network
- `ip route show | grep -i 'default via'| awk '{print $3 }'`

output: `192.168.0.1` for me

**NOTE**:

For 15.04 and later, there is no `nm-tool` , so use `nmcli dev show <IFACE>`.  For example,

```
$ nmcli dev show wlan7 | grep GATEWAY                                                                                    
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

**Edits and additional info**

As you can see from examining the command, we take output of `nm-tool` (which,note, takes information from NetworkManager), find line containing word `gateway`, print than information with echo (separated by spaces), and then cut off only second item of that whole output. Note, that if you have two or more connections there, you may need top remove `xargs echo | cut -d' ' -f2` part, and replace it with `awk '{print $2}'`; in other words the whole line would look like this `nm-tool | grep -i gateway | awk '{print $2}'`. Alternatively you could have used `nm-tool | grep -oP '(?i)gateway:\s*\K\S+'` as proposed by Avinash Raj in the comments. As you can see there is nothing special done here , and the whole ordeal here is merely an exercise in using output editing tools such as cut, awk, and grep.

Another method of getting the gateway information is through `nmcli dev list` (yes, still relying on network manager) command. `nmcli` is the command - line version of network manager. You could run `nmcli dev list | grep -i routers` or you could run `nmcli dev list | grep -i 'gw ='` . Again, you could exercise in in cutting of all the other info except the desired ip address, if you wanted to.

Since in the original question the only specification was to print the default gateway only, I am relying on output of nm-tool here. NetworkManager comes with Ubuntu by default, this is the standard way for managing Ubuntu's network connections. If you use something other , like wicd or connect through wpa_cli, nm-tool won't provide you an answer. In such case you may find other people's answers bellow more useful.

A more distro-neutral, and config-neutral option would be to use `netstat -n` , which uses kernel routing table, similar to `route -n`. 
It's output is bellow, nothing surprising.

```
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

And here's the way to cut out your desired info : `netstat -nr | awk '$1 == "0.0.0.0"{print$2}'`

Another one, neutral as well: `arp -n | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: simple `nm-tool | grep -oP '(?i)gateway:\s*\K\S+'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks ! I haven't studied grep and awk much in depth so operating on the knowledge i already had. This will be good to know

Comment: Perhaps this is due to some (additional) peculiarity of my configuration, but on a machine with adapters `eth0` and `wlan0`, both actively connected but with a gateway configured only on `wlan0`, `nm-tool | grep -i gateway | xargs echo | cut -d' ' -f2` outputs merely `0.0.0.0`. `nm-tool | grep -oP '(?i)gateway:\s*\K\S+'` outputs two lines: `0.0.0.0` followed by `192.168.1.1`. (The [`ip route ...`](https://askubuntu.com/a/605429/22949) and [`route -n ...`](https://askubuntu.com/a/605432/22949) ways produce just `192.168.1.1`, which I would consider the most desirable result.)

Comment: This won't work if the network is not being managed by `network-manager` e.g. by `ifupdown` or `ifconfig`..in those cases `nm-tool` won't generate desired output..in a nutshell this answer solely relies on the network being managed by `network-manager`..

Comment: @EliahKagan Ah, I see. In case of my command, it finds lines with 'gateway' in it, then echoes it as one line separated by spaces, and cuts off the second item in it. Because you have two such lines there, my command only prints one of them. Avinash's command is better in this case. As for 0.0.0.0, here's something [related](http://superuser.com/a/46443). As for heemayl's comment, yes, that's true, and there were no specifications in the OP's question other than just to show the output

Comment: Thanks for the added explanations in the edit! One thing though: doesn't `arp -n` list *all* cached IP addresses for machines on the same [layer 2 network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer) as the host? I think the only time the gateway is the only IP address listed is when it's the only other machine the host has communicated with recently on a LAN. For example, when I run it, it lists the IP of my gateway (via `wlan0`, through which I connect to the Internet) and also the IP of a machine I recently `ssh`ed into (through `eth0`, which is connected to a LAN containing no routers).

Comment: That's true. Should I add a "disclamer" to it or just remove that one ?

Comment: :D :D :D Another one-liner: "Upvoted"!  ;-)

Answer (score 15):

You can find it many ways

```
ip route show default
```

A better question, what or how do you want to shape the output ?

```
ip route show | awk '/default/ {print $3}'

tracepath -m 1 8.8.8.8 | awk '/1:/ {print $2}' | uniq
```

From the comments -(thank you  Avinash Raj 0

```
tracepath -m 1 8.8.8.8 | awk '/1:/ {print $2;exit}'
```

Comment: you don't need to o for `uniq` just `tracepath -m 1 8.8.8.8 | awk '/1:/ {print $2;exit}'` would be 5in.

Comment: so many choices. On my system it prints twice w/o uniq. YOur solution works also.

Comment: Note `tracepath` supports `-m` on [some versions of Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/tracepath.8.html) but [not on others](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/tracepath.8.html).

Comment: By the way, @bodhi.zazen, there's variation on your answer , use traceroute . Same idea different command, right ?

Comment: @serg sure, there is probably a long list of commands and filtering options, sed, awk, perl, grep ...

Answer (score 7):

As you usually use `route -n`, you can try this `sed` solution coupled with `route -n`:

```
route -n | sed -nr 's/(0\.0\.0\.0) +([^ ]+) +\1.*/\2/p'
```

Here is a test:

```bsh
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

$ route -n | sed -nr 's/(0\.0\.0\.0) +([^ ]+) +\1.*/\2/p' 
192.168.1.1
```

Another way would be to use `grep`:

```bsh
$ route -n | tr -s ' ' | grep -Po "(?<=0\.0\.0\.0 )[^ ]+(?= 0\.0\.0\.0)"
192.168.1.1
```

As @AvinashRaj has pointed out this can be done by only using `grep` (no need to squeeze the spaces using `tr`):

```bsh
route -n | grep -Po "0\.0\.0\.0\s*\K\S+(?=\s*0\.0\.0\.0)"
192.168.1.1
```

Comment: you don't need to use `tr`, grep alone will do the job `route -n | grep -Po "0\.0\.0\.0 \s*\K\S+(?=\s*0\.0\.0\.0)"`

Answer (score 1):

I use this one quite often:

```
route -n | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep -Eo '[1-9]{0,3}\.[1-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{0,3}\.[1-9]{0,3}'
```

Comment: What if the address is `192.168.0.1` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a web browser on the system you can go to http://whatsmyrouterip.com/ and it should be able to find your ip without any command.

Otherwise simply opening the terminal and doing a `ip route | grep default` should be enough. It might give more than one depending on your network interfaces tho.

Answer (score 0):

I use this quite often and easy to remember:

```
route | grep default | awk '{print $2}'
```