# How to get my dhcp ip address via terminal, whether i am in a local network?

Tags: command-line

How to get my dhcp ip address, whether i am in a local network?

I.e. if we have internet access in local network, but i want to know my dhcp server IP .. like " what is my IP" ..

Comment: `ifconfig` gives informations about your network adapters. `eth0` is the first (and probably only) ethernet adapter. It's current IP address is listed as `inet address`.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**
Your question was worded in slightly confusing way. Getting your public IP form terminal can be done with `curl https://diagnostic.opendns.com/myip`. Open DNS has web service that tells you your IP address, which is pretty much just a web page , with only one text - your IP. Effectively, you are downloading a web page that tells you your IP.

**Original**

Typically `dhcp` server is located on the router. Thus , your main goal then is to get address of the router, which in networking terms would be `default gateway`. Thus , effectively your question can be solved by the multiple solutions as described in my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/605476/295286). The simplest method is to use `netstat -nr` command.

There is another method as well: `nmcli dev list | grep -i dhcp_server_identifier` (Ubuntu 14.04 and earlier).  Sample output for that would be:

```
$ nmcli dev list | grep -i dhcp_server_identifier                              
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
```

With Ubuntu 15.04 the `nmcli` version is different, hence you have to enter slightly different command:

```
nmcli dev show | \grep 'gw ='
```

Side note : `grep` in my install of 15.04 is aliased to `grep --color=auto` which prints colorized output. If we want just to see the particular lines, we need to use simple `grep`, which the forward slash instructs the shell to use.

Comment: I have a local IP 192.168.1.22 and i want to know my public IP. how can i know from terminal..

Comment: Check my edit. Also, your question is effectivelly duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/95910/295286

Answer (score 1):

What is my ip shows you the public IP of your gateway. If this is what you are looking for you wan use:

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com
```

Comment: `dhcp server`   is a different term from `public IP` address. The `dhcp server` is what assigns a local IP address to a machine. For example, if my IP address on the network is `192.168.0.69` then where does it come from ? From the router, meaning that `dhcp server` is located at address 192.168.0.1, which is router local IP.

Comment: I know, and you are totally right. Otoh, if you google 'what is my ip' you get your public ip address. In typical home broadband connections the router acts as a dhcp server and a gateway (as, most likely, you already know) so I think this is what OP was asking.